# Oracle: Possible to replace a standard non-unique single column index with an unique combined index?

Tags: oracle, performance, indexing

I´m currently working on optimzing my database schema in regards of index structures. As I´d like to increase my DDL performance I´m searching for potential drop candidates on my Oracle 12c system. Here´s the scenario in which I don´t know what the consequences for the query performance might be if I drop the index.

Given two indexes on the same table:
- non-unique, single column index IX_A (indexes column A)
- unique, combined index UQ_AB (indexes column A, then B)

Using index monitoring I found that the query optimizer didn´t choose UQ_AB, but only IX_A (probably because it´s smaller and thus faster to read). As UQ_AB contains column A and additionally column B I´d like to drop IX_A. Though I´m not sure if I get any performance penalties if I do so. Does the higher selectivity of the combined unique index have any influence on the execution plans?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could do, though it's quite likely to be minor (usually).  Of course it depends on various things, for example how large the values in column B are.

You can look at various columns in USER_INDEXES to compare the two indexes, such as:

- BLEVEL: tells you the "height" of the index tree (well, height is BLEVEL+1)
- LEAF_BLOCKS: how many data blocks are occupied by the index values
- DISTINCT_KEYS: how "selective" the index is

(You need to have analyzed the table first for these to be accurate). That will give you an idea of how much work Oracle needs to do to find a row using the index.

Of course the only way to really be sure is to benchmark and compare timings or even trace output.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I´ll check USER_INDEXES, especially the index height should be helpful to decide whether to drop the index or to keep it. Nevertheless I´ll give it a try and drop the indexes and see how my benchmakrs perform. I just wasn´t sure if there´s some systematic difference in how Oracle uses unique combined indexes in its execution plan computation.